# How to find MacLaurin series for $\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I’m asked to find the terms up to $x^2$ for the MacLaurin series of $\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$.

I get $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}\right) = \frac{\frac{\cos(x)}{x}-\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}}{2\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}}$, which is undefined for $x = 0$.

But the same happens at the second derivative; undefined for $x = 0$.

Do I just take the limit of the derivative? How do I get around this?

Hints appreciated, no solution please.

Comment: Do you know the MacLaurin series of $\sin(x)$ and of $\sqrt{1+x}$?

Comment: it's undefined at $x=0$, so are its derivatives. I doubt you can find its MacLaurin series. Maybe do a Taylor series around $x=\varepsilon$ and take limit $\varepsilon$ approaching zero.

Comment: Are you sure this singularity is not removable? As $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ has a removable singularity at $x=0$ via $1$ seen by L'Hospial for example.

Comment: You indeed just take the limit $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\cdots.$$

So if $\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1+ax+bx^2+\cdots$ then:

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\left(1+ax+bx^2+\cdots\right)^2$$

So $2a=0$ and $2b+a^2=-\frac{1}{6}$. So what are $a,b$?

Comment: Gonna call this the best answer, certainly the one that was most intuitive to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The series for $\sin(x) $ is $x - x^3 / 3! + x^5 / 5! - \ldots$. So that for the quotient is

$$
f(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \ldots.
$$
Now, can you find a quadratic polynomial whose square is those first three terms? If you can, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to *compose* series (expanded up to order $2$):

- $\dfrac{\sin x}x=\dfrac{x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)}x=1-\dfrac{x^2}6+o\bigl(x^2\bigr)$
- $\sqrt{\mathstrut1-u}=1-\dfrac u2-\dfrac{u^2}8+o\bigl(u^2\bigr),$

whence (the composition has to be truncated at order $2$)
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}x}=1-\frac{x^2}{12}+o\bigl(x^2\bigr).$$

Answer (score 1):

Since in a neighbourhood of the origin we have
$$ \frac{\sin x}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{x^4}{120}-\ldots \tag{1}$$
and $\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$ is an even analytic function in a neighbourhood of the origin,
$$\sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}= 1 + a x^2 + b x^4+\ldots \tag{2}$$
where by squaring the RHS of $(2)$ we have to recover the RHS of $(1)$. That implies:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}}=1-\frac{x^2}{12}+o(x^3).\tag{3} $$

---

We also have a straightforward generalization of this approach. Assuming
$$ \sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{x}} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n a_n}{n!} x^{2n}\tag{4}$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{a_k a_{m-k}}{k!(m-k)!} = \frac{1}{(2m+1)!}\tag{5}$$
hence the coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ can be computed through a simple recursion, given $a_0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{equation}\label{S(n,k,x)-satisfy-eq}
R(n,k,r)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}(r+j)^n
\end{equation}
for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$. The quantities $R(n,k,r)$ are called weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind in Carlitz's paper [1] below.

A general answer to this question is the following theorem which is stated in Theorem 1 of the paper [2] below.

**Theorem.**
For $r\in\mathbb{R}$, assume that the value of the power function $\bigl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\bigr)^{r}$ at the point $x=0$ is $1$.

1. For $r\ge0$, the series expansion
   \begin{equation}\label{recip-sin-ser-closed-eq}\tag{SEH}
   \biggl(\frac{\sin x}{x}\biggr)^r=1+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^m\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\frac{(-r)_k}{k!}
   \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \frac{R\bigl(2m+j,j,-\frac{j}2\bigr)}{\binom{2m+j}{j}}\Biggr]\frac{(2x)^{2m}}{(2m)!}
   \end{equation}
   is convergent in $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where the rising factorial $(r)_k$ is defined by
   \begin{equation*}%\label{rising-Factorial}
   (r)_k=\prod_{\ell=0}^{k-1}(r+\ell)
   =
   \begin{cases}
   r(r+1)\dotsm(r+k-1), & k\ge1;\\
   1, & k=0.
   \end{cases}
   \end{equation*}
2. For $r<0$, the series expansion \eqref{recip-sin-ser-closed-eq} is convergent in $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

References

1. L. Carlitz, *Weighted Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, I*, Fibonacci Quart. **18** (1980), no. 2, 147--162.
2. Feng Qi, *Series expansions for any real powers of (hyperbolic) sine functions in terms of weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind*, arXiv (2022), available online at https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.05612 or https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.